# Adding mini icon over an icon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons

I need to put an mini icon in red color which responds as a counter over this icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
```

It's to show the number of question of a determinate field value.

Comment: I was thinking about a canvas solution, I don't know what is the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using bootstrap or not. That would be nice, but anyway, I used Bootstrap for my answer only to make use of the badge class but you can style the badge class as you please. SO don't expect the badge class to work as I have it without Bootstrap (in terms of styling only, round corners, etc,)

Anyway, what you need is to enclose your number or whatever it is you are using over the icon in a span tag and position it with relative positioning and some tweaking.

Here is the css :

```
  .badge{
     vertical-align:top;
     position:relative;
     right:12px;
     background:red;
  }
```

And [***here***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxbXMa) is the working code

Comment: No problem! glad I helped